# CN1 project not showing build hints and mobile properties on Windows10

Tags: codenameone

I have copied the  project from my old amchine to  windows 10 machine. Application works without any problem on simulator. If I right click to see the properties, I don't see IOS, Android and build hints. Please advise if there is something I'm missing here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This was removed ages ago in Codename One 5.0 but was deprecated before that. See https://www.codenameone.com/blog/removing-old-preferences.html

You should use Codename One Settings in the right click menu.